# TryCatch not printing warning unless warning is wrapped in ()

Tags: r, try-catch

TryCatch is not printing the warnings unless the warning is wrapped in between brackets.

```
tryCatch(
  {
  print(wd)
},
error=function(e){
 (warning(sprintf('Watch out %s',e)))}
)
```

prints the warning ""Watch out Error in print(wd): object 'wd' not found\n"

but

```
tryCatch(
   {
 print(wd)
    },
    error=function(e){
     warning(sprintf('Watch out %s',e)) }
    )
```

does not.

Any idea why? How can I fix this? This example is a minimal example. I have a much bigger function that runs through a loop and I don't necessarily want to stop the loop if there is an error but I want to see the warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your loop you probably want to use `message` or `cat`, e.g.:

```r
for (i in 1:2)
    tryCatch(print(wd),
             error = function(e) message(sprintf('Watch out %s',e)))
## Watch out Error in print(wd): object 'wd' not found
## 
## Watch out Error in print(wd): object 'wd' not found
```

To understand what is happening in your two versions:

- `warning` does not print anything. It signals a warning, which a
  handler might print immediately or arrange to be printed later.
- If a handler does not execute a non-local transfer of control,
  e.g. to a `tryCatch`, then `?warning` says this about the value it
  returns:

> Value:
>
> ```
> The warning message as ‘character’ string, invisibly.
> ```

- If an expression returns a result invisibly, then enclosing it in parentheses
  makes the result visible. Help files often use the idiom

  ```r
  (x <- foo(y))
  ```

  to make the result of the assignment visible and have the top level print it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Using messages  will definitely be more useful for my purposes.